# Blender GPU rendering works from command line but not in crontab

Tags: command-line, bash, cron, gpu, blender

I would like to schedule blender renderings with GPU support. I have created a bash file rendering.sh to do the job. I have scheduled it with `sudo crontab -e`.

```
* * * * * sleep 0 ; sudo /Home3DHome/Scripts/rendering.sh
```

My problem is that it rendrers with CPU. (45 minutes by frames)
But if I start the bash file manualy from command line: `sudo /Home3DHome/Scripts/rendering.sh`

It works like charm. GPU rendering (25 seconds).

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like missing environ variables. I'd bet on `PATH`. Get your current `PATH` by running

```
echo $PATH
```

in Terminal. Then add a line

```
export PATH=<output_from_above>
```

at the start of your script

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. Maybe it is with my nvidia driver... In an other installation of ubuntu it had worked well without environment variables.
I had to reinstall ubuntu and I did something different because now it doesn't work.